# How can I print output with decimal places in C programming

Tags: c

I have been trying to use all the possible placeholders that I thought right but I am still not getting it. My output is rounding off all the decimal values to zeros. How can I correct the code? This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*Program to calculate the average of any numbers*/
int t=0, m=0;
int main ()
{
    int n=1;
    int s;
    double avg;
    do 
    {
        printf ("List your sales one by one hitting enter, enter 0 to end list\n");
        scanf ("%d", &s);
        t+=s;
        m++;
        n++;
    }
    while (s!=0);

    avg=t/(m-1);
    printf ("Your average sales is %.4lf.\n", avg);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are `t` and `m` declared _outside_ `main()`?  It is unnecessary and bad practice to have wider scope than necessary.

Comment: Note that `l` is not a meaningful modifier for `%f` for `printf`. It is, however, meaningful for `scanf`, which is not symmetrical.